# Cramér-Rao lower bound - Estimator is independent of the parameter

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, independence, estimation

I have followed the Cramér-Rao lower bound (CRLB) derivation, and I couldn't figure out why -

If $f(x; \theta)$ be a probability density with continuous parameter $\theta$, and $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be independent random variables with density $f(x; \theta)$, and $\Theta(X_1, \dots ,X_n)$ be an unbiased estimator of $\theta$.

Why does the estimator, $\Theta$, is independent of $\theta$ (the param to be estimated)?

$\Theta$ is a function of $X_1, \dots, X_n$, and in the pdf of each one of them $\theta$ appears as a param. Doesn't it imply that $\Theta$ is also dependent on $\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too fond of the use of the word "independent" in this context. What the author meant is that the estimator $\Theta = \Theta (X_1, \ldots , X_n)$ is a function **only** of the data, and not of the parameter $\theta$ to be estimated. Intuitively, we want to be able to observe $\Theta$; since $\theta$ is an unobservable (yet, estimable) quantity, we don't want to incorporate it in the definition of $\Theta$.

The fact that $\theta$ appears in the density of $X_i$ will mean that it will appear in the density of $\Theta$, but this does not mean that $\Theta$ is a function of $\theta$.

Comment: So what is the derivative of Θ by θ? (dΘ/dθ)?
Throught the CRLB derivation it was assumed that dΘ/dθ = 0, but you say that θ will appear in the expression for Θ, so how does it make sense?

Comment: @Jonathan $\theta$ appears in the *density* of $\Theta$, not in the computation $\Theta$ itself. Take as an example the case where $X_i \sim N(\mu , 1)$, and you set $\Theta = \overline{X}_n = \frac{1}{n}(X_1 + \ldots + X_n)$. Notice that $\overline{X}_n$ does not depend on $\mu$, but its density does (since $\overline{X}_n \sim N(\mu, 1/n)$). You can see from the above that $\frac{d \Theta}{d \theta} = 0$